# python function to interpolate the value at a point in a 2D field

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I have a 2D pressure field and I would like to interpolate the value at
particular set of singular points or locations. I'm suspect downscaling is a solution but before I try and write the functions for python, I was wondering if there is a way/code already in existence. Perhaps scipy has a function but I'm unaware and cannot find any.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scipy has a 2-dimensional interpolation function:

```
    scipy.interpolate.interp2d
```

Information on how to use this function can be found on http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html

```
    scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z)
```

in which `x` and `y` are 1-dimensional arrays of coordinates corresponding to the two dimensional array `z` which is your pressurefield.

`x` corresponds to the second axis of the `z`-matrix.
`y` corresponds to the first axis of the `z`-matrix

Comment: I'm not looking to regrid the data. Apologies if my original text misled you. I'm looking to interpolate to locations, e.g., say London, NY, Cape Town, etc.